# Laravel relationship gives me "?" instead of email

Tags: laravel

I'm setting this relationship

```
public function nonAcceptedContracts()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserContract::class, 'invite', 'email', 'usercontract')->where('status', 'pending');
}
```

And calling it like that.

```
$user->loadMissing('nonAcceptedContracts');
dd($user->nonAcceptedContracts()->toSql());
```

What I get is

```
"select * from `usercontract` inner join `invite` on `usercontract`.`id` = `invite`.`usercontract` where `invite`.`email` = ? and `status` = ? and `usercontract`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

The query seems to be the one I'm looking for but why do I get this question mark there? Shouldn't be there the email of my user model? Also the "status" value, should be "pending" and there is another question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how `toSql()` works. What you are seeing is a **parameterized query**. These parameterized queries allow type-specific value when replacing the `?` with their respective value. They are frequently used when executing dynamic SQL from a program.

You can read more on this topic here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel

If you really want to see the actual queries, try enabling the **query log**. One thing to note here is that this logfile can grow very large on a busy server.